# how to create a list of abbreviation

Tags: tables, lists, acronyms

How can i create list of abbreviation to looks like that

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tabularx, multirow, makecell, rotating} %
    \usepackage{enumitem}

        \begin{document}
        \begin{center}
    \bfseries
\settowidth\rotheadsize{List of Abbreviation/accronym}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
    %\hline
%\multicolumn{3}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}%
                 %p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{\cellcolor{gray!30}
    %Les sujets (traduits)}    \\
    \hline
\cellcolor{gray!30} Abbreviation & \cellcolor{gray!30} Explanation     \\
    \hline
\multirow[b]{2}{*}{USA}   
            & \cellcolor{blue !30}  United state of america
 \rule[-1em]{0pt}{2.5em} \\
    \cline{2-2}
   & 
   \rule[-1em]{0pt}{2.5em} \\
    \cline{2-2}
    &    \rule[-1em]{0pt}{2.5em} \\
    \hline
        \multirow[b]{2}{*}{NY}   
            &  \cellcolor{blue !30} New york 
 \rule[-1em]{0pt}{2.5em} \\
    \cline{2-2}
   & 
   \rule[-1em]{0pt}{2.5em} \\
    \cline{2-2}
    &     \rule[-1em]{0pt}{2.5em} \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: 4 gold badges, over 1000 rep and still no mwe? -1 from me

Comment: I 'm working on it

Comment: What you are calling "abbreviations" are better known as "acronyms".  Look up `acro` and/or `acronym` packages.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Technical an acronym is an abbreviation that can be pronounced as a word, although it's increasingly being used as a synonym for abbreviation.

Comment: yes Thank you but do you know any package in acronyms can create this kind of list

Comment: @Educ With the `glossaries` package you can provide your own styles. You might want to start with just a `tabular` environment and work out how to make that look like your desired output, and then progress to transferring that to a style that can be integrated with whichever package you want to use.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I work for the government, and I *assure* you that any string of upper cased letters can be "pronounced as a word," vowels notwithstanding.  Thus, I stand by my comment. `;^)`

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Examples, H-HMMWV pronounced Humvee, CSTA pronounced "siesta", AHPCRC pronounced ahipcrick, NMAH pronounced "enema".

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Now you're going to make me search for obscure abbreviations made up of X, Q and Z `;-)`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes talking of seaking words, how is your name pronounced? 1. Where is the stress and 2. do you say the last 'e'? --> Séglets, Segléts, Ségletes, Seglétes, Segletés, Séglete:s, Segléte:s, or Segleté:s, where é is a stress and e: is an elongated e?

Comment: @thymaro I have been called many things, but as my wife likes to say, pronounce it akin to "sick lettuce".

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes works for me.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just commented 6 lines of input

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tabularx, multirow, makecell, rotating} %
    \usepackage{enumitem}

        \begin{document}
        \begin{center}
    \bfseries
\settowidth\rotheadsize{List of Abbreviation/accronym}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
    \hline
\cellcolor{gray!30} Abbreviation & \cellcolor{gray!30} Explanation     \\
    \hline
\multirow[b]{2}{*}{USA}   
            & \cellcolor{blue!30}  United state of america
 \rule[-1em]{0pt}{2.5em} \\
    \cline{2-2}
%   & 
%   \rule[-1em]{0pt}{2.5em} \\
%    \cline{2-2}
    &    \rule[-1em]{0pt}{2.5em} \\
    \hline
        \multirow[b]{2}{*}{NY}   
            &  \cellcolor{blue!30} New york 
 \rule[-1em]{0pt}{2.5em} \\
    \cline{2-2}
%   & 
%   \rule[-1em]{0pt}{2.5em} \\
%    \cline{2-2}
    &     \rule[-1em]{0pt}{2.5em} \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: could you make this table spilt in tow pages

Comment: @Educ I answered using the structure you proposed in your question, and the question had nothing to do with page breaking.  I suggest looking at `longtable` and seeing if it can be adapted to your needs.

Comment: @Educ It makes better sense to ask a new question, rather than to redefine the scope of the original question after answers have been provided.  Perhaps providing a link back to this question, with the new question asking how to adapt the solution to break across page boundaries.

Comment: okay I'll do it

Comment: @Educ Great.  I will roll back your question to a prior edit, so as to avoid confusion on this one.